# Meaning of “the bolts that held his face together”

Tags: meaning-in-context

**What does “bolts” mean here**?

> I used to crouch down into the seat and hold my coat in front of my face when I sensed a frightening scene coming, peeking through the buttonhole to find out when it was over. Through the buttonhole Frankenstein’s monster glowered; lightning flashed; sweat poured over **the bolts** that held his face together.
>
> From the short story “The Movie House” written by John Updike

Comment: Ok.Thnaks. The book ''Patterns : a short prose reader. Fifth Edition.''

Comment: Would you please give me the topic idea of this passage?

Comment: @Reaserchee - I'm going to edit your question to remove the excess information and the extra question. Please feel free to submit a new question asking about the topic (but explain what you mean by *the topic idea*)

Comment: Ok.Much obliged. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly a description of Frankenstein's monster or something similar. A **bolt** is a parallel-sided screw that is usually held in place by a [nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nut_(hardware)).

[image]

Comment: Note that "bolt" might be used in a metaphorical sense, alluding to the Frankenstein monster.

Answer (score 2):

The second definition at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bolt) is:

> A long pin with a head that screws into a nut, used to fasten things
> together.